# Yield* construct "jumps a value" if the iterable argument is a generator function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I have an unexpected behavior with the following code:

```js
function* innerGeneratorFn() {
  yield 'foo';
  return 'bar';
}

function* outerGeneratorFn() {
  console.log('iter value:', yield* innerGeneratorFn());
}

for (const x of outerGeneratorFn()) {
  console.log('value:', x);
}
```

The construct yield* wants an Iterable and `innerGeneratorFn()` is an Object Generator that in turn it's a Iterable too. The value of yield* is ,generally speaking, the value property accompanying done:true of the associated iterator. For classical iterators this value will be undefined. But for iterators produced from a generator function, this value will take the form of whatever value is returned from the generator function (innerGeneratorFn() in this case).

The output of the code above is:

```
value: foo
iter value: bar
```

instead I would have expected the following output:

```
value: foo
value: bar
iter value: bar
```

Indeed this similar version of early code:

```js
function* innerGeneratorFn() {
  yield 'foo';
  return 'bar';
}

function* outerGeneratorFn() {
  console.log('iter value:', yield*['foo', 'bar']);
}

for (const x of outerGeneratorFn()) {
  console.log('value:', x);
}
```

I will have in output:

```
value: foo
value: bar
iter value: undefined
```

Why in the first code version the output `value : bar` is not there?

Comment: Your second snippet has `iter value: undefined` as its actual output. In no case would `bar` be used twice!

Comment: @Bergi Yes, it's a copy-paste mistake. I'm going to correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this is what `return` means in a generator function -- it is used to hand a value back to the `yield*` expression, *not* to produce the last element in the generated sequence.

It sounds like you meant to write this:

```
function* innerGeneratorFn() {
   yield 'foo';
   yield 'bar';
}
```

Which will have the behavior you want.

Note that you could also `yield yield* innerGeneratorFn()` to accomplish the same thing without changing `innerGeneratorFn()`, but I would consider than an anti-pattern. It will only work with generator functions that use `return`, of which very few actually will -- and when they do, it will be for a specific reason.

---

Further reading:

- [Iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)
- [`function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*), which states:

  > A `return` statement in a generator, when executed, will make the generator finish (i.e. the `done` property of the object returned by it will be set to `true`). If a value is returned, it will be set as the `value` property of the object returned by the generator.
- [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*), which states:

  > The value of `yield*` expression itself is the value returned by that iterator when it's closed (i.e., when `done` is `true`).

Comment: Yes, you have centered my misundestanding. I believed that the done property associated to return in a generator was done:false too. Thanks to explication.